# Creating DOM content dynamically

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I'm just playing around with some Firefox extension programming and I came across a question. Let's say I want to create a kind of grid, each line consist of a lot of elements.
If I want to add x rows to a panel dynamically, I assume I have to do it with that:

```
for(var i=0; i<x; i++) {
   tempButton = document.createElement("button");
   tempLabel = document.createElement("label");
   tempWhatever = document.createElement("button");
   ...
   tempButton.setAttribute("label", "YippeYeah");
   ...
   container.appendChild(tempButton);
   container.appendChild(tempLabel);
   container.appendChild(tempWhatever);
}
```

Isn't that a bit painful? Thinking about nested vbox, hbox, styles, ... for formatting all the elements to get a good layout?

Would it be possible to create a user defined .js object that consist of the element information for the button, the label and the Whatever; then associate a "template"-.xul file for reuse with every grid row and do only a

```
for(var i=0; i<x; i++) {
   container.appendChild(myObjArray[i]);
}
```

to build the grid less painfully.

Does it make sense or am i wrong?
Regards,
Alex

Comment: I haven't tried though, how about doing it in the innerHTML way?

Comment: @shinkou: Bad suggestion, using innerHTML in extensions is a frequent source of security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Wladimir, I don't do it myself tho, security concerns?  How?  I'd like to know more.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: @shinkou: Sure. Typical code looks like this: `element.innerHTML = "<description>" + text + "</description>;"`. If `text` happens to be something that comes from a webpage, a malicious webpage can give you something like `<img src="dummy" onerror="alert('Malicious code here')"/>` and now it already managed to run JavaScript code with privileges of your extension (meaning that it is allowed to do anything). You *could* escape special characters in `text` but that's complicated and something that's easy to forget. Using DOM methods is inherently secure on the other hand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, creating interfaces dynamically with DOM methods is kind of painful. You might want to use [XBL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Introduction_to_XBL) instead.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where you don't want to/cannot use XBL you can also take a template node and clone it. I typically have a node in my document like this:

```
<hbox id="rowTemplate" hidden="true">
  <button class="hiButton" label="Hi!"/>
  <description class="explanation"/>
  ...
</hbox>
```

And I create the actual row like this:

```
var container = document.getElementById("rowTemplate").cloneNode(true);
container.removeAttribute("id");
container.removeAttribute("hidden");
container.getElementsByClassName("hiButton")[0].setAttribute("foo", "bar");
container.getElementsByClassName("explanation")[0].textContent = "Try this";
...
```